# Syncml(500): The recipient encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request - Intune Bitlocker

Tags: azure, bitlocker, microsoft-intune, mdm

When trying to enable encryption (BitLocker) from Intune using a profile under Windows10_EndpointProtection
, it throws out an error like this:

**Syncml(500): The recipient encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request**

ERROR CODE
**0x87d101f4**,

It has no documentation or clarification anywhere, if anyone knows anything about it then please share it asap.

*TIA,*

Comment: did you enable the default Baselines recently?